# Accelerate the ruby on rails website

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, redis, unicorn, sunspot-solr

I am running ruby on rails website with unicorn as app server and nginx as web server. Which is okay for the time being,but in spite of having CDN in the place, the response time of the website is too slow.Also I am using Sunspot solr for searching and index but its running in another ec2 ubuntu instance and also redis server which is also running in another server.

How do I optimize the site and make it faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a great plugin for Chrome called [PageSpeed](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/) which scores your pages and gives you ideas for optimisation, such as minifying JS and CSS, making sure images are the best size, getting your browser to cache as much as possible and so on.

There's also a good pro [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/369-client-side-performance) about client side performance.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you could also have a look at the Bullet gem. It helps to kill N+1 queries and unused eager loading. There is a nice Railscast about it! [Bullet Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/372-bullet)

Answer (score 2):

Another helpful gem could be MiniProfiler. There is also a [nice Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/368-miniprofiler) about it. It allows you to see the speed of a request conveniently on the page. It also shows the SQL queries performed and allows you to profile a specific block of code.